# Getting 400 error on openai Image generation api project

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling, openai-api

Im having a 400 error in my console. I checked the code many times. But cant figure out the problem.
My api key and url is correct.

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c8AI.png)

Here is my js code

```js
const API_KEY = "000000000000000000000"; 
const submitIcon = document.querySelector("#generateButton");
const inputElm = document.querySelector("#inputPrompt"); 
const imageSection = document.querySelector(".image-section");

const generateImages = async () => {
  const promptText = inputElm.value;

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      prompt: promptText,
      n: 4,
      size: "1024x1024",
    }),
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations",
      options
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    data?.data.forEach((imageObject) => {
      const imageContainer = document.createElement("div");
      imageContainer.classList.add("image-container");
      const imageElement = document.createElement("img");
      imageElement.setAttribute("src", imageObject.url);
      imageContainer.appendChild(imageElement);
      imageSection.appendChild(imageContainer);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

submitIcon.addEventListener("click", generateImages);
```

I was expecting some ai generated image based on user input prompt. But this error keeps coming.

Comment: 400 means Bad Request (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400). Your request is badly formed for some reason. Do you have access to the server-side?

Comment: what is the complete error message in `console.error(error);`

Comment: @Yilmaz here is the error.

`POST https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations 400
generateImages @ script.js:23
`
`Error: HTTP error! Status: 400
    at HTMLButtonElement.generateImages (script.js:29:13)
generateImages @ script.js:43`